# Android Studio button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio; and I was wondering how would I create buttons that would take integer as an input.

Comment: Please clarify more else question might be closed. Also do mention anything that you've tried. Is it that `Button` should have text which is a number or you want an `EditText` which takes number and on Button press, something happens?

Comment: To be more specific I want Button to have number in it, not EditText to take number.

Comment: You can simply set it as string: `String.valueOf(number)`

Comment: Would I have to do it in XML file?

Comment: Inside Java class. You can also use android:text inside xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean an `EditText` that accepts only `integer` entry. You can do it by adding this to the `EditText` code in your xml:

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this have number in the button itself?

Comment: What do you mean by " have number in the button itself"? Can you explain further?

Comment: So basically I am taking 4 different inputs as a pincode. So my approach to it was to use 4 different buttons, and the buttons would take inputs as numbers. If the pincode is correct, it goes to secondary activity.

Comment: You can use `EditText` for this no need to use buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this you click a number of buttons to create a PIN code 4 digits long and if it is the correct PIN code off you go to a new screen (Activity) so here is a few lines of code that get a String str from a database and test the value of str from the database against a string value in an editText etPW

```
    /*========================================================================================
    Notice the btnEnter has <=NO=> addListenerOnButtonEnter() defined
    so how does it know what to do ? How to respond to the click event
    Look at btEnter in the XML file take note of this property android:onClick="onEnter"
    So the btnEnter when clicked executes the code in the method onEnter
 ==========================================================================================*/
public void onEnter(View view) {
    str = helper.getCol_MPW();
    if(str.equals(etPW.getText().toString().trim())){
        etPW.setText( "" );
        str = "";
        Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class );
        startActivity( intent );
    } else {
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        etPW.setText( "" );
        etPW.requestFocus();
    }
}
```